# Could not send form data in PHPUnit?

Tags: symfony, functional-testing, phpunit

I am new to PHPUnit with Symfony 2.
I have a problem sending form data to client. I have login details needed to log in the page. so i send it as array. Every time i run test i got Error Message as:

There was 1 error:

1) MySite\UserBundle\Tests\Controller\LoginControllerTest::testUser
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

My Test Code is:

```
public function testUser()
 {
    $client = static::createClient(array(), array());
    $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/login');
    //submit login data
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
    $data = array(
    '_username' => 'abc@testSite.com',
    '_password' => '123',
    );
    $client->submit($form,$data);
    $client->followRedirect();
    $this->assertTrue($client->getReponse()->isSuccessful());

    //$this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("login")'));
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Dashboard")')
      ->count() > 0);
}
```

I don't know from where the error came from.
I just wanted to validate the user with username and password. And check whether they have successfully accessed to Dashboard or Not.
The user is valid user, can be logged from browser.
Any help will be highly appreciated !

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line on the testcase do the error?

Comment: $form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form(); and the error is: InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
        $client = static::createClient(array(), array());
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter("form")->count() > 0, "Login form exist");
        $form = $crawler->filter("form")->form();
        $client->submit($form, array(
            '_username' => $username,
            '_password' => $password,
        ));
        if ($client->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
        }
//        die(var_dump($this->client->getResponse()->getContent()));

       $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Dashboard")')->count() > 0);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi, I tried with your given code, The error is in the same line  $form = $crawler->filter("form")->form(); saying InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

Comment: And the assertion before ( "Login form exist") don't fail? If yes check the response checking the value of $client->getResponse()->getContent()

Answer (score 0):

The normal way would be to write:

```
$form['_username'] = $username;
$form['_password'] = $password;
```